# Sql queries on string columns - sorting according to language

Tags: sql

I have a column of name, varchar(200).
In this column data can be filled in hebrew and english.

I have code that does queries on this DB, I want to have the option to sort the results - first hebrew and then english - and the other way as well.

How can it be done? if at all...

Comment: Do you have a column that specifies the language?

Comment: No I do not have this column since I do not know this when inserting.

Comment: If you don't know when inserting, how do you know when selecting?  It would be far easier and more efficient (and scalable) to have an additional column identifying the language.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This would sort any name with a Hebrew character on top, and in Hebrew order.  The other names would be sorted in English order:

```
select  *
from    YourTable
order by
        case 
        when name like '%[... all hebrew letters here ...]%' then name
        end collate Hebrew_CI_AS
,       name collate Latin1_General_CI_AS
```

In a collation, `CI` means Case Insensitive. `AS` means Accent Sensitive.

Comment: But the question if I can do - select * from Table order by name xxx???   that will get first the hebrew then english - in same query but sorted accordingly?

Comment: I think you can recognize Hebrew names by the characters they have?  Answer updated if that's true.